# Fedora touchpad drivers not working on lenovo laptop

Tags: fedora, fedora-33

I got a new lenovo s145 laptop, installed fedora 33 but the touchpad seems not to working. I have connected it to an external mouse (its working) but I'm not comfortable.

I have installed synaptics using dnf:

```
sudo dnf install xorg-x11-drv-synaptics -y
```

But it does not do anything.

Comment: Are you using the driver from Lenovo? Why not?

Comment: The computer does not come with touchpad drivers, hence you have to install them from the official lenovo website but they  only have drivers from windows version, so I was wondering if there are other alternatives @CharlesKenyon